# Restricted group user to use a specific apps on Django

Tags: python, django, permissions

I have three apps in my Django's Portal. I like to allow the specific group users to use a specific apps. For Example:

- app1 --> group user 1
- app2 --> group user 2
- app3 --> all users

So, group user 1 can use app1, but they can't use app2, and so on.

How can I do this?

Thanks!